# LocalDateTime with additional comment

Tags: java

I have this date :

```
2019-09-18T11:00:00 (COMMENT)
2019-09-18T12:00:00
2019-09-18T14:00:00
2019-09-18T17:00:00 (COMMENT)
```

This dates came directly as `LocalDateTime`.

Later I want to use `toString()` to print those LocalDateTime.

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss' (COMMENT)'";
String date = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-09-18T17:00:00 (COMMENT)");

System.out.println(pattern); //yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss '(COMMENT)'
System.out.println(date); //2019-09-18T17:00:00 (COMMENT)

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern));

System.out.println(ldt.toString()); //2019-09-18T17:00:00
```

The problem is at dates with `(COMMENT)`, it is missing.

How I can print date with it?

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` object does not have the capability to store such a comment, so this is not possible to get this from only a `LocalDateTime` object. You'll have to make your own class to store the timestamp and the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could split string and then hand date.

Something like this:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
String date = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-09-18T17:00:00 (COMMENT)");

System.out.println(pattern); //yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss '(COMMENT)'
System.out.println(date); //2019-09-18T17:00:00 (COMMENT)

String[] split = date.split(" ")

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(split[0], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern));

System.out.println(ldt.toString()); //2019-09-18T17:00:00
```

Comment: I don't want just date. I want date together with `(comment)` and don't lose it when I parse `String` to `LocalDateTime`. But @Jesper comment clarified it. It's not possible without a custom class.